# How to join lists (references) into a single one

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have 2 lists with complex (similar) hashes in them and i want to iterate over both lists within a single loop to not duplicate the code (I also do not want to make a block or macro)

```
testList1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
testList2 = [6,7,8,9,10,];

FOREACH item IN [testList1 , testList2]; # <--- ???
  doSomething = doSomething _ 'useful ' _ item;
END;
```

The above statement creates a new list that contains only the references to the lists, but i want a temporary list with their contents.

How can i achieve this without extra manual list building logic. Is there some construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list VMethod `merge()` will do the job:

```
[% testList1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5] %]
[% testList2 = [6,7,8,9,10,] %]

[% doSomething = '' %]
[% FOREACH item IN testList1.merge(testList2) %]
  [% doSomething = doSomething _ 'useful ' _ item %]
[% END %]
[% doSomething %]
```

See http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_merge for more information.